# Server side variable in client side custom validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I have a custom validator on a page:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server"  
     ControlToValidate="ddlProposer" ErrorMessage="Please select some values."  
     Display="Dynamic" onservervalidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" 
     ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator2_ClientValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

It must be valid, when a server-side list is not empty (or: the `ListCount` variable > 0). This list may change after the page has been loaded (via buttons on update panel):

```
public partial class Pages_Application_Application : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected List<IdValue> ProposersList
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["proposersList"] == null)
                ViewState["proposersList"] = new List<IdValue>();
            return ViewState["proposersList"] as List<IdValue>;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["proposersList"] = value;
        }
    }

    public int ListCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ProposersList.Count;
        }
    }
...
```

There is no problem with server-side validation:

```
protected void CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = this.ProposersList.Count > 0;
}
```

The problem is with client-side part. I've been trying something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CustomValidator2_ClientValidate(source, arguments) {
        var serverVariable = <%= ListCount %>;
        alert(serverVariable);
        arguments.IsValid = serverVariable > 0;
    }
</script>
```

however, it fires only on first page load, and the ListCount variable is always 0 (so does the serverVariable).

The question is: is there an easy-way to make it working? So the Javascript gets the **current** value of some server-side variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use hidden variable on the page level and by setting its value from server side and validate on client side.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="ListCount" runat="server" value="0" />


public partial class Pages_Application_Application : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected List<IdValue> ProposersList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["proposersList"] == null)
            ViewState["proposersList"] = new List<IdValue>();
        return ViewState["proposersList"] as List<IdValue>;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["proposersList"] = value;
        ListCount=value; 
    }
}

public int ListCount
{
    get
    {
        return this.ProposersList.Count;
    }
}


<script type="text/javascript">
function CustomValidator2_ClientValidate(source, arguments) {
    var count= document.getElementById("ListCount").value;
    alert(count);
    arguments.IsValid = count > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it in plain javascript, and there is no sens of getting the server side variable since it won't be up to date at the moment client validation will be done.

What you need is pass your ddl html element to your `CustomValidator2_ClientValidate` function and check if it contains `option` html elements, that should do the trick.

Comment: That dropDownList is only a "source" list, it always contains options. It's on update panel with repeater. After selecting something from the list and pressing "add" button, selected option is added to server list (`ProposersList`), then it's bind do repeater and updatePanel is updated. So that solution will not work.

Comment: @mj82 you should add that explanation in your question, and yes it won't work that way then. Which elements are generated by the repeater? Could you post your html code (the part generated by repeater)?